# Using quantifiers to rewrite some simple mathematical statements

Tags: logic, logic-translation

Have I used quantifiers correctly to rewrite these sentences?

> The equation $x^3=7$ has at least one root.

$∃x∈\mathbb R\;\;x^3-7=0$

> The equation $x^2-2x-5=0$ has no rational roots.

non$(∀x∈\mathbb Q \implies x^2-2x-5=0)$

***EDIT***: Or how about $∀x∈\mathbb Q \implies x^2-2x-5≠0$ ?

> Every equation on the form $x^3=a$ has one root.

$∀a∈\mathbb R \:\:∃x∈\mathbb R \;\;x^3=a$

Comment: for number 2 if "non' means not, you mean exists not for all.

Comment: Number $2$ is confusing.  if "non" is meant to negate what follows then it is wrong.  The negation of "every rational is a root" is "at least one rational isn't a root". It is not "no rational is a root."

Comment: Then how else can I write the expression "The equation x^2-2x-5=0 have no rational roots"? Is this more valid then "∀x∈Q ⇒x^2-2x-5≠0"

Comment: @Marcus K. Johnson What you wrote isn't a valid sentence in the Language of Set Theory. Consider, ∀x ( x∈Q ⇒ x^2-2x-5≠0)

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: please learn to use Latex and then rewrite post

Answer (score 2):

> > The equation $x^2-2x-5=0$ has no rational roots.
>
> non$(∀x∈\mathbb Q \implies x^2-2x-5=0)$
>
> ***EDIT***: Or how about $∀x∈\mathbb Q \implies x^2-2x-5≠0$ ?

1. The *fragment* $$∀x∈\mathbb Q\tag1$$ is informal and means $$\text{for every $x$ that is in $\mathbb Q$},$$ which is **not** a sentence.
2. Therefore, the sentence $$∀x \,\Big(x{∈}\mathbb Q \implies P(x)\Big)$$ can be abbreviated as $$∀x{∈}\mathbb Q \:\:P(x)\\\text{$P(x)$ holds for every rational $x$}.$$
3. Fragment $(1)$ means **neither** $$∀x \:\,x∈\mathbb Q\\\text{for every $x,\:x$ is rational}\\\text{everything is rational}$$ **nor** $$\text{every $x$ is rational}.$$

---

> non$(∀x∈\mathbb Q \implies x^2-2x-5=0)$

This isn't a coherent sentence. The modification $$\text{not $(∀x\,x∈\mathbb Q \implies x^2-2x-5=0)$}$$ means: everything is rational yet $x^2-2x-5\ne0.$

> ***EDIT***: Or how about $∀x∈\mathbb Q \implies x^2-2x-5≠0$ ?

This too isn't a coherent sentence. Based on the previous section, the correct answer is $$∀x \,\Big(x∈\mathbb Q \implies x^2-2x-5≠0\Big)$$ or, equivalently, $$∀x \,\Big(x^2-2x-5=0 \implies x\not∈\mathbb Q \Big)$$ or, equivalently, $$\lnot\exists x \,\Big(x^2-2x-5=0 \;\land\; x∈\mathbb Q \Big).$$

Comment: Another way to write #2 (if you want the NOT to come in front like in the pre-edit guess) is $\neg\;\exists\,x,\;(x\in\mathbb Q\;\wedge\;x^2-2x-5=0)$, which can be abbreviated as $\neg\;(\exists\,x\in\mathbb Q,\;x^2-2x-5=0)$.

Comment: @TobyBartels I've edited in your suggestion.